# Are some lightsabers "stronger"?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Kylo Ren has a seemingly "crude" lightsaber. This is due to [a lot of things](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111425/why-does-kylo-rens-lightsaber-look-different-from-normal-lightsabers), but it seems to hold up pretty well, even against a lightsaber made by a Jedi (almost) Master. But throughout the movies, all lightsabers are basically shown to be indestructible, other than at the hilt.

So then what are the advantages of having a "refined" lightsaber, other than showing that you know how to build one? Are some lightsabers not only better quality, but actually stronger or more stable than others? Has there ever been an instance of a lightsaber blade "breaking" because it was weaker during combat?

---

This is different from [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111425/why-does-kylo-rens-lightsaber-look-different-from-normal-lightsabers) because I'm not asking specifically about what makes Kylo's lightsaber different (I already read that question, that's why it's linked). I'm asking specifically if there are combat advantages to having a really good quality lightsaber.

Comment: Kylo's lightsaber has more grimdark particles.

Comment: Well there's a scene in *The Force Awakens* where Kylo slashes someone up the back with his saber, and instead of becoming two separate pieces the guy just sort of... falls down. So maybe some sabers are weaker against flesh than others.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet or maybe Disney is not a fan of traumatizing children, or killing a main character in the first movie in a trilogy.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet according to the novelization, Kylo Ren does not slash the guy, but ignites the sword, so that it impales him, and then switches it back off.

Comment: @Lexible Grimdachlorians?

Comment: In the "KOTOR" games you could modify the lightsabres (i.e. by changing the crystals) to change their properties and make them weaker/stronger.

Answer (score 2):

According to [**Wookieepedia**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal):

> While the most common crystals used in the process were from the Adega system, Ilum, and Dantooine (in the so-called Crystal Cave), Jedi and Sith used a variety of crystals to produce various colors, effects and unique abilities. Some crystals could even enhance the Force skills of a particular user.

And also it seems that some Sith lightsabers were a bit stronger then Jedi ones:

> Sith-made synthetic crystals created a slightly more powerful blade when energized by the dark side of the Force. Sith lightsaber blades could occasionally "break" the blade of a Jedi saber.

Comment: FWIW that Wookieepedia link is to the Legends article.

Comment: +1 for the research, but I was hoping for a canon answer.

Comment: Well, I don't have any clue about other canon hints about what you asked. I remember that somewhere it was stated/infered that when Obi-Wan fought Vader on the first Death Star, his saber almost break because Vader's lightsaber was superior. But I can't find the mention of this.