# What happened to ‘old’ lightsabers pre Empire?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, lightsaber

In TPM we see Obi-Wan use Qui-Gon's lightsaber to defeat Dart Maul. In AOTC Anakan and Obi-Wan are thrown a couple as they have had their own taken away or destroyed, and in ANH and TESB Luke uses the last lightsaber used by Anakin.

So, ‘a lightsaber is suited to its creator’ aside, what became of lightsabers with no owners?

For example, a Jedi dies of old age/natural causes, would his lightsaber be property of the Jedi Order and be used in training or carried around as spares as in AOTC?

Comment: [Very related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176751/58193) though doesn't seem to be a dupe as it is more asking what happened after the creation of the Empire.

Comment: There is also a question about the legality of possessing a lightsaber during the Empires reign. I do hope mentioning ‘pre-empire’ this won’t get voted down....

Comment: there was a "sharps" container at each Jedi temple.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/263289/21154

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Legends, some lightsabers were requested for museum exhibits about the Jedi. If they weren't requested for a museum, Jedi with families (mainly the Green Jedi of Corellia and some other variant traditions) often had theirs returned to family members.

> A friend of his came here, bringing Nejaa [Halycon, a Green Jedi]'s effects home. He apologized for not having Nejaa's body.... He also didn't have Nejaa's lightsaber. He said the Galactic Museum had asked for it for their Jedi collection.

-- from *I, Jedi*. This is partially a reference to a scene in the earlier-written, later-set *The Krytos Trap* where, indeed, Nejaa's lightsaber turns up in a museum collection dedicated to memorials of noteworthy Jedi.

Most Jedi don't keep in contact with their families, of course; in those cases I would imagine that their lightsabers are passed to Padawans or peers, but I don't have a citation for that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 9):

In Legends it is mentioned in the comic *Star Wars: Jedi Council: Acts of War* Issue 4 that the lightsabers of fallen Jedi are sometimes hung in the Jedi temple "if it is worthy".

[image: Micah dies and asks his lightsaber be hung in the temple]

Answer (score 4):

According to the canon novel *The Rising Storm*, during the High Republic era, standard practice was to send them to "the repository."

> Stellan's hand went instantly to the long silver lightsaber hilt he obviously thought Elzar hadn't noticed, tucked away beneath his robe. "Shouldn't that be in the repository?" Elzar asked.
>
> "It will be," Stellan told him, subconsciously pulling his cloak

The novel *Into The Dark*, from the same era, describes a monument made of retrieved kyber crystals.

> Each crystal in the arch was a kyber crystal, one retrieved from the damaged lightsaber of a Jedi fallen in battle.

Perhaps lightsabers from Jedi who died in battle were treated differently, or perhaps it has to do with whether the crystals sustained damage.

Comment: There's also a High Republic-era monument made from the crystals of fallen Jedi lightsabers: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/263290/21154

Comment: @MiloP Edited to include that info