# What happens to lightsabers after large battles?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Do the hilts just sit there? I'm specifically refering to huge battles like Geonosis or the 7th Battle of Ruusan. Is there someone who scavenges the sabers, or do the Jedi/Sith send people to recover them? Of course we have to mention this guy when talking about the Clone Wars though:

[image: General Grievous]

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on who won the battle?

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176751/58193).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would depend on the circumstances of the battle, but it appears that the Jedi preferred to retrieve the fallen lightsabers in memoriam.

In Canon, [*The High Republic: Into the Dark*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_High_Republic:_Into_the_Dark) describes a monument within the Jedi Temple known as the [Kyber Arch](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyber_Arch), which was built from lightsaber crystals of Jedi who had died in battle:

> Each crystal in the arch was a kyber crystal, one retrieved from the damaged lightsaber of a Jedi fallen in battle. As beautifully as it sparkled in the light, it was a reminder of the price their fellow Jedi had paid in the pursuit of justice over the past millennia.
>
> (*The High Republic: Into the Dark*, via [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Star_Wars_The_High_Republic_Into_the_Dar/ManSDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0))

In the case of the (first) Battle of Geonosis, the Republic won the battle and subsequently [occupied the planet](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Occupation_of_Geonosis), according to *The Clone Wars*, so the Jedi likely reclaimed the lightsabers of their fallen, though as far as I know this hasn't been explicitly confirmed.

However, there's at least one example of a battle where the lightsabers were left where they fell. In the *Rebels* episode *Twilight of the Apprentice*, Ezra, Kanan, and Ahsoka visit Malachor, the site of an ancient battle, still littered with petrified remains:

[image: Screenshot from Rebels showing petrified bodies]

There, Ezra finds ancient (and still working) lightsabers:

[image: Ezra holding a crossguard lightsaber in a screenshot from Rebels]

The 2017 *Darth Vader* comic series later established that after Order 66, fallen Jedi's lightsabers were rounded up and melted down in a public ceremony, though in this case the executions were separate and not part of a single large battle:

[image: Panels from Darth Vader comic showing Mas Amedda throwing lightsabers into a forge]

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the Jedi won the battle of Geonosis, so it's likely they picke up their own lightsabers